# NSBitmapImageRep.bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace() calling deprecated CGContextClear

Tags: macos, opengl

I'm trying to use

```
NSBitmapImageRep.bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace(NSColorSpace.genericRGBColorSpace(), renderingIntent: NSColorRenderingIntent.Perceptual);
```

to convert an NSImage to a format that can be handled by openGL, and it works (unlike bitmapImageRepByRetaggingWithColorSpace()), but I get an error:

```
<Error>: The function ‘CGContextClear’ is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
```

which is sort of useless, because it's Apple's own code, and I can't seem to find an alternative to bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace(), or any note that it too is deprecated.

EDIT:

```
                var image=NSImage(size: frame);
                image.lockFocus();
                //println("NSImage: \(image.representations)");
                string.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(0.0,0.0), withAttributes: attribs);
                var bitmap2=NSBitmapImageRep(focusedViewRect: NSMakeRect(0.0,0.0,frame.width,frame.height))?;
                image.unlockFocus();
                    bitmap=bitmap2!.bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace(NSColorSpace.genericRGBColorSpace(), renderingIntent: NSColorRenderingIntent.Perceptual);
```

Comment: What representations are attached to your NSImage?

Comment: None I think?>  nsimage.description="<NSImage 0x608000262340 Size={1465.2520276531577, 299} Reps=()>"

I create it using NSImage(size: frame);, then draw to it using NSString.drawAtPoint() after locking the focus

Comment: check nsimage.representations.count just to be sure.  I didn't know you could have an NSImage with no representations.

Comment: From the Apple NSImage Docs:  the class itself knows little about the underlying image data. Instead, it works in conjunction with one or more image representation objects.

Comment: @jwlaughton maybe I should have asked for the representation after drawing to it...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this question interested me.  It looks like the solution is to lock focus on your NSImage, then use NSBitmapImageRep(focusedViewRect:) to create the NSBitmapImageRep.

I tried to recreate your situation (as I understand it) and then create an NSBitmapImageRep with the following code:

```
var img:NSImage = NSImage(size: NSMakeSize(200,200))
img.lockFocus()

let testString:NSString = "test String"
testString.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(10,10), withAttributes: nil)

img.unlockFocus()

println("img Description = \(img.description)")
```

I got the following description:

img Description = NSImage 0x608000067ac0 Size={200, 200} Reps=(
    "NSCGImageSnapshotRep:0x61000007cf40 cgImage=CGImage 0x6100001a2bc0")

I then extended this code to:

```
var img:NSImage = NSImage(size: NSMakeSize(200,200))
img.lockFocus()

let testString:NSString = "test String"
testString.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(10,10), withAttributes: nil)

img.unlockFocus()

println("img Description = \(img.description)")

img.lockFocus()

var bitmapRep:NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(focusedViewRect: NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, img.size.width, img.size.height))!

img.unlockFocus()

println("bitmap data planes = \(bitmapRep.bitmapData)")
println("bitmap pixels wide = \(bitmapRep.size.width)")
println("bitmap pixels high = \(bitmapRep.size.height)")
println("bits per sample = \(bitmapRep.bitsPerSample)")
println("samples per pixel = \(bitmapRep.samplesPerPixel)")
println("has alpha = \(bitmapRep.alpha)")
println("is planar = \(bitmapRep.planar)")
println("color space name = \(bitmapRep.colorSpace)")
println("bitmap format = \(bitmapRep.bitmapFormat)")
println("bytes per row = \(bitmapRep.bytesPerRow)")
println("bits per pixel = \(bitmapRep.bitsPerPixel)")
```

The output for the NSBitmapImageRep parameters was:

bitmap data planes = 0x000000010b6ff100

bitmap pixels wide = 200.0

bitmap pixels high = 200.0

bits per sample = 8

samples per pixel = 4

has alpha = true

is planar = false

color space name = Color LCD colorspace

bitmap format = C.NSBitmapFormat

bytes per row = 800

bits per pixel = 32

Comment: I've edited my post with the full code I'm using.  bitmap2 works fine on my older iMac running 10.10, whose default colorspace seems to be 'iMac', however it doesn't work on my newer Macbook (running 10.9), which produces an sRGB colorspace.  All the other bitmap properties are the same as yours

Comment: I just noticed something about your code.  You say you're using bitmap2, but it looks to me like in your code bitmap is the rep with the converted colorspace.  In my code (my last post) bitmapRep2 is the rep with the converted colorspace.

Comment: BTW I'm running 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted some new code below.  I've created two NSBitMapImageRep just like your code (except that I used the method bitmapImageRepByRetaggingWithColorSpace), and I exported both of them to a PNG file.  I got the same image in both PNG files.

But I'm wondering a couple of things.  First, the difference in your two tests was not only the OS X version, but the hardware produced different color spaces.  You should check to be sure bitmap2 is not nil.

Second, I'm wondering if OpenGL cares.  If bitmap2 is not nil and you pass OpenGL bitmap2.bitmapData, does it work?

My new code (deleting most of the println):

```
var img:NSImage = NSImage(size: NSMakeSize(200,200))
img.lockFocus()

let testString:NSString = "test String"
let font:NSFont = NSFont(name: "AppleCasual", size: 18.0)!
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.LeftTextAlignment
let textColor:NSColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

let attribs:NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle]

testString.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0), withAttributes: attribs)

img.unlockFocus()

println("img Description = \(img.description)")

img.lockFocus()

var bitmapRep:NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(focusedViewRect: NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, img.size.width, img.size.height))!

img.unlockFocus()

let pngPath:String = "TestStringBeforeChange.png"

let imageProps = [NSImageCompressionFactor: NSNumber(float: 1.0)]
let outputImageData = bitmapRep.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: imageProps)

let fileSavePanel = NSSavePanel()
fileSavePanel.nameFieldStringValue = pngPath

var savePanelReturn = fileSavePanel.runModal()

if savePanelReturn == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton
{
    var theFileURL = fileSavePanel.URL
    var saveStatus = outputImageData?.writeToURL(theFileURL!, atomically: true)
}

let bitmapRep2 = bitmapRep.bitmapImageRepByRetaggingWithColorSpace(NSColorSpace.genericRGBColorSpace())

let pngPath2:String = "TestStringAfterChange.png"
let outputImageData2 = bitmapRep2!.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: imageProps)

let fileSavePanel2 = NSSavePanel()
fileSavePanel2.nameFieldStringValue = pngPath2

var savePanel2Return = fileSavePanel2.runModal()

if savePanel2Return == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton
{
    var theFileURL2 = fileSavePanel2.URL
    var saveStatus2 = outputImageData2?.writeToURL(theFileURL2!, atomically: true)
}
```

Comment: neither of the bitmaps ever ends up as nil.  On my older, 10.10 machine, all three versions work with openGL, but on the 10.9 machine only the bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace() bitmap works.

Comment: I got all three versions to run on my wife's 10.9.4 machine today.  Maybe your problem has to do with the way you're creating and populating the textures?  I'm using OpenGL and GLSL shader Language versions 4.1.

Comment: When I say I got all three to run, I mean I loaded the .bitmapData into a texture and ran it through my shaders on both my 10.10 machine and the wife's 10.9 machine.  All versions displayed as expected in an NSOpenGLView.

Comment: I think I've taken this as far as I can.  It may be that when I compiled and ran this on our 10.9 machine I changed the deployment target, or it may be something else. On the 10.10 machine I was running Xcode 6.1.1 with a deployment target of 10.10.  On the the 10.9 machine I was running Xcode 6.1 with a deployment target of 10.9. Good luck to you on this one buddy, but I just can't duplicate your failures.  Maybe we can help each other again in the future.

Comment: BTW thanks for posting this question and your responses.  It has taken me down a path to explore new ways of of implementing text in an NSOpenGlView.  For that: Good on ya mate!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the posts, but I don't want to let this go, and it's interesting.

I created 3 PNG files: the first using the original NSBitmapImageRep, a second using an NSBitmapImageRep created with bitmapImageRepByRetaggingWithColorSpace and a third using an NSBitmapImageRep created with bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace (I, of course, got the system warning when I used this function).

Looking at these three PNG files in Preview's Inspector, they were all RGB color models; only the colorSynch profile for the first file was different from that of the second and third file.  So I thought maybe there's no difference in the bitmapData among these files.

I then wrote some code to compare the bitmapData:

```
var firstRepPointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = bitmapRep.bitmapData
var secondRepPointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = bitmapRep2!.bitmapData
var firstByte:UInt8 = 0
var secondByte:UInt8 = 0

for var i:Int = 0; i < 200; i++
{
    for var j:Int = 0; j < 200; j++
    {
        for var k:Int = 0; k < 4; k++
        {
            memcpy(&firstByte, firstRepPointer, 1)
            firstRepPointer += 1
            memcpy(&secondByte, secondRepPointer, 1)
            secondRepPointer += 1

            if firstByte != secondByte {println("firstByte = \(firstByte) secondByte = \(secondByte)")}
        }
    }
}
```

As I expected, there were no differences when I compared the bitmapData from the original bitmap rep to the bitmapData from the bitmap rep created with bitmapImageRepByRetaggingWithColorSpace.

It got more interesting, however when I compared the bitmapData from the original bitmap rep to the data from the bitmap rep created with bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace.

There were lots of differences in the data. Small differences, but lots of them.

Even though there were no differences I could see in the PNG files, the underlying data had been changed by bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace.

All that said, I think you should be able to pass .bitmapData from any of these bitmap reps to an OpenGL texture.  The data from the bitmap rep created with bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace might create a texture that looks different, but it should be valid data.

Comment: I compared these three PNG files side by side.  The color in the first and third files are bright and vibrant.  The color in the second file is a little washed out.  I think this is because for the second PNG file the colorSynch profile was changed without adjusting the underlying data.